# Angular ng-repeat nested array

Tags: angularjs

I've got this array

```
 {
    "menus": [
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Administrator",
            "icon": "symbol-male",
            "is_show": "1",
            "sub_menus": [
                {
                    "id": "6",
                    "admin_menu_id": "4",
                    "name": "Manage Admin Role",
                    "link": "admin-roles",
                    "is_show": "1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5",
                    "admin_menu_id": "4",
                    "name": "Manage Administrator",
                    "link": "admins",
                    "is_show": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I ng-repeat with the sub_menus properly with the menus?

I've tried

```
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="menu in menus">{{ menu.name }}
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="sub_menu in menu.sub_menus">{{ sub_menu.name}} </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

But the sub_menus.name not shown when I repeat it.

Comment: It should works. I think you just have issue with css. Please show your code in controller

Comment: It seems to be working perfectly fine. Here, I replicated your code in this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/peMRlg?p=preview

Comment: hmm. odd. why mine is not reproduce any data on sub_menu.

Comment: @sstarlight: maybe you could check out the way I did. How are you storing data? Is it on $scope.menus?

Comment: Hi, i've found the problem within my other JS. it prevent it to show because of an element. Thanks. i've tried yours outside my container it's working perfectly. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html need to be something like below.

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="menu in menuItems.menus">{{ menu.name }}
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="sub_menu in menu.sub_menus">{{ sub_menu.name}} </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Have alook at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2v26xd4t/)

Comment: The ng-repeat needs to be perform on array. So your main ng-repeat needs to be on menus which is part of your main json response which is not of type array. Have a look at JSFiddle. If it cant resolve the problem share your JsFiddle and will help you to get it resolve.

Comment: Hi, i've found the problem within my other JS. it prevent it to show because of an element. Thanks. i've tried yours outside my container it's working perfectly. :)